# VBA Script to check if table exist on MS ACCESS, Delete if it does

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need to implement a check to see if TableA exists, if it does, drop the entire table. If it doesn't, i will create the table. I couldn't really find out if this is possible to implement on VBA / MS Access.

In SQL we can use:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TableA
```

Anybody has any idea how this can be implemented? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the [TableDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820997.aspx) collection where you iterate through items and conditionally drop or create using same DDL SQL statements passed in code.

```vb
Dim db As Database 
Dim tbldef As TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb

For each tbldef in db.TableDefs 
   If tbldef.Name = "TableName" Then 
      db.Execute "DROP TABLE " & tbldef.Name, dbFailOnError
   End if 
Next tbldef

db.Execute "CREATE TABLE TableName (...rest of SQL...);", dbFailOnError    

' UNINITIALIZE OBJECTS 
Set tbldef = Nothing 
Set db = Nothing
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a much easier way to do this than the code above.

```
On Error Resume Next
  currentdb.execute "DROP TABLE TABLENAME;"
On Error Goto 0
```

What this does is tries to delete the table and skips the line if an error is generated because the table does not exists. Only 3 lines and runs faster.